# using subquery factoring result in where clause

Tags: oracle, subquery-factoring

Why can't I use a subquery factoring clause result in the where clause of as depicted in the following sql:

```
with rpt as(
 select * from reports where caseid = 
 :case_id and rownum=1 order by created desc
)
select 
 distinct rt.trialid
from 
 report_trials rt
join 
 trial_genes tg on rt.id=tg.trialid
where 
 rt.reportid = rpt.id
and 
tg.gene not in('TMB','MS')
```

The subquery is named `rpt`and used in the select statement's where clause. When executed encountering the following error: `ORA-00904: "RPT"."ID": invalid identifier`

*UPDATE*:

In fact nested query for the same thing is also giving me the same issue. The nested subquery is only returning a single column value from a single row:

```
select 
 distinct rt.trialid
from 
  report_trials rt
  join 
  trial_genes tg on rt.id=tg.trialid
where 
 rt.reportid = (select id from reports where caseid = :case_id and 
  rownum=1 order by created desc)
and 
 tg.gene not in('TMB','MS')
```

Comment: you need to add the table rpt in your query.

Comment: Your first question is about an error and the edited question is about another topic. Please accept my first answer first then I will reply on your 2nd question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed to add the table rpt in your query, thus that error.

```
with rpt as(
 select * from reports where caseid = 
 :case_id and rownum=1 order by created desc
)
select 
 distinct rt.trialid
from 
 report_trials rt
join 
 trial_genes tg on rt.id=tg.trialid
join 
  rpt on rt.reportid = rpt.id
where  
  tg.gene not in('TMB','MS')
```

Comment: I am trying to understand why we can only use this subquery in a join even when the results of the subquery is scalar(having one column value for one row). So if you take out the `*` and replace it with `id` in the column, I still run into the same issue. Please review the OP update.

Comment: the subquery is in a firm of a table (temp) so you need to join it to make use of it.